# Speed up mySQL SELECT query, 1st query takes 1000 times longer than next?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple ISAM table with 1.6 million records. The typical query has a WHERE clause on 3 indexed columns and returns 10,000 or so records. For purposes of this question, I'm doing SELECT * and I'm leaving out ORDER BY . The only unusual thing about the table is that it has 1 large non-numeric column VARCHAR(8192).

For the queries I'm using for this question, the first query submission takes about 145 seconds while subsequent submissions take about 2 seconds. The table is worthless in this state since the real queries I need to do will take an hour or more on the first submission. This seems ridiculous, no matter how much disk I/O is being done. When I'm using an INTO OUTFILE version of my queries, mySQL can write enormous files to disk in a tiny amount of time ...

How can I fix this table?

```
#key_buffer_size=256M
#tmp_table_size=64M
#max_heap_table_size=64M
#myisam_sort_buffer_size=88M
#read_buffer_size=1M
#read_rnd_buffer_size=2M
```

Responding to questions:

Table is about 2.2GB 1.6 million records.

Speed: doesn't need to be fast, just fast enough to avoid dying of old age while waiting ... 5 seconds would be acceptable for what is now taking 2 minutes.

Information returned by EXPLAIN:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(200000)*/ *  
FROM tbl_skews 
WHERE (skw_minute IN(43)) 
  AND (tday_date >= 42767 AND tday_date <= 42838) 
  AND (skw_days > -10 AND skw_days < 70);

 id     1

 select_type     SIMPLE          
 table       tbl_skews     
 partitions      NULL           
 type    ref      
 possible_keys      ndx_skews_tday_date,ndx_skews_skw_minute,ndx_skews_skw_days     
 key                     ndx_skews_skw_minute     
 key_len        2    
 ref        const     
 rows       35396    
 filtered   1.51    
 Extra           Using where
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spx_opts`.`tbl_skews` (    
`exp_true_date` INT NOT NULL,    
`exp_subndx` TINYINT NOT NULL,    
`tday_date` INT NOT NULL,    
`skw_minute` SMALLINT NOT NULL,    
`skw_TS_load` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`tday_days_to_next` SMALLINT NOT NULL,    
`tday_is_early_close` TINYINT NOT NULL,    
`tday_open_time` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`tday_close_time` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_opar_pmod` SMALLINT NOT NULL,    
`prs_opar_yield` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_best_yield` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_best_pvdiv` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_rate_libor` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_rate_used` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_rate_implied1` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_rate_implied2` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_TS_min` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_TS_max` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`prs_is_exp_linked` TINYINT NOT NULL,    
`skw_is_chain_good` TINYINT NOT NULL,    
`skw_TS` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`skw_und_print` FLOAT NOT NULL,    
`skw_days` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`skw_ndx_m_pvdiv` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`skw_vol_atm` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`skw_cvix` DOUBLE NOT NULL,    
`skw_stk_vol` VARCHAR(8192) NOT NULL,    
PRIMARY KEY (`exp_true_date`, `exp_subndx`, `tday_date`, `skw_minute`),    
INDEX `ndx_skews_tday_date` (`tday_date`),    
INDEX `ndx_skews_skw_minute` (`skw_minute`),    
INDEX `ndx_skews_skw_days` (`skw_days`))    
ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Comment: Second query always will be faster because will get the data from the cache.  Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Question was edited to answer questions ...

Comment: Question was edited to make table definition more clear.

Comment: add 4 spaces or select text and press control-k to format as code

Comment: Hopefully have it formatted as code now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create composte index for `skw_minute, tday_date, skw_days`

```
create index my_idx on my_table(skw_minute, tday_date, skw_days);
```

Comment: Ok, the composite index was big progress ... my test query time went from 145 seconds to 3 seconds. I don't understand why the extra index is necessary ... thought I was following best practices of "enough indexes, not too many." Unfortunately, the query I need to run every day still takes 90 seconds to pull just 44,000 records ... is there anything else I can do?

Comment: I dont understand, you test query run in 3 seconds but you have a different query running on 90 seconds?? What is the query?? Where is the PLAN?? You need to anayze the explain plan to understand the query and optimize it. And Best practice is the one solving the problem. If you need one index you create that index. Check here MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: It's the exact same query, just with a wider date range and skw_minute IN() with 7 values instead of 1 value ... I could never run it until now because it would have taken hours. Thanks for the tips link, I will study.

Comment: Looks like my problem now has to do with the large VARCHAR column, so will ask a new question ... thanks Juan for breaking the logjam.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the indexes. Indexes are something like a primary key but you could have multiple indexes in one table.

For example, if I have the following query

```
select * from users where email='christakos@gmail.com'
```

i have to index the email column.

You can view this video to learn more about indexing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjNef3tPltU

Comment: ensure that you are following those steps http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/24/improving-the-performance-of-large-tables-in-mysql.html

Comment: That list is mostly about innodb ... I started this project with innodb and moved to isam because innodb performance was much worse than isam (keep in mind that I only care about reads, not writes ... my understanding is that isam normally performs better for this case.)